# Limit number of files in a specific folder

Tags: unix

I have a cronjob that creates a database backup every day at 3.30am.

Nomenclature for the filename is live_YYYY_MM_DD.sql.gz where YYYY, MM and DD are the dates of the day the backup was made.

Normally, I go in and delete older backups, but I want to limit the number of backups to the 3 most recent ones.  Is there any way to do that via some kind of process or script?

Thanks

edit:

I edited logrotate.conf as per http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/

Comment: @holygeek you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

A simple shell script can do the job but you'd be better off learning the standard tool for doing it: [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html). When your requirement for older backup file management changes, instead of modifying a home-brew script it will be just a matter of changing a logrotate config entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -t live_*.sql.gz|awk 'NR>3'|xargs echo
```

If this echos the right files, use `rm` instead of `echo`. Place it at the proper place in your backup script and you don't need to install logrotate.